# How to remove file with hard link 0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rm, hardlink

I've tried to remove linux files from windows but they hadn't been deleted.
I tried to remove from Ubuntu terminal but get "permission denied"
I set chown $USER:$USER and chmod 777 for parent directories and files also try sudo it did't help at all
I install Ubuntu 20 from windows store.
I use command `sudo rm {my filename}`

[file list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pov92.png)

Comment: "*I install Ubuntu 20 from windows store*" This is WSL?

Comment: @xenoid This was WSL, yes

Comment: I have this same problem and will provide some context that may be relevant. For me, the file I cannot remove is a CSV file that I had opened in Excel at some point. The file is not visible when using FileExplorer and running 'ls -l' shows that it has 0 links. Here is a post that may be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389682/cannot-delete-a-file-on-wsl-ubuntu-20-02-2#:~:text=You%20most%20likely%20either%20had,on%20a%20completely%20different%20drive..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and was able to solve it by shutting down WSL using PowerShell. First I ran `wsl --list --verbose` to get the version of Ubuntu I had running. Then I ran `wsl -t Ubuntu` to shut WSL down. After, starting WSL up again the file was gone.